# How do i declare button on Click listen in a fragment to switch to an activity?

Tags: android-fragments, fragment, onclicklistener, implements

I tried but i am getting errors "Onclick listener can't be applied here" Please help me guys

Here is my `Fragment.java`

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment {

    public Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        final Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.payment_info);
        final Button button1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.redeem);
        final Button button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.make_payment);
        final Button button3 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.payment_histories);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to me, i mean how to tell the button to go that fragment after i have declared the on click listener E.G.    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              >>>>>>>>>What do i do here to switch to fragment
            }
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnClickListener is an interface, so you have not to only extend the fragment but to implement the OnClick.

Try this on your declaration of the class:

`public class Fragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener`

Hope it helps.